# why does the VW dealers in NA have a different battery than OEM?

Tags: battery, vw, part-identification, parts, jetta

My 2008 Jetta 2.5L SE came with the following OEM battery in North Carolina:

```
e ENERTEC
EMC
1J0 915 105 AD
12V 61 Ah 330A DIN
540A EN/SAE
```

(Note that some appear to come with ***VARTA*** as the OEM vendor, but mine's definitely ***ENERTEC***.)

However, dealers in New Mexico and Texas that I've called in 2014/2015, told me that they only have batteries with a VW part number of `000 915 105 DE`, which they claim is the correct part number for my car.  One of them claimed that the part number changed from `AD` to `DE`, and noone could really explain the `000` part in place of the `1J0`.  They said that the manufacturer of the battery varies with a batch, and some batches were made by Interstate with a green cap, and some were made by Enertec with a Volkswagen logo and black caps.

- What's the difference between my `1J0 915 105 AD` and the proposed replacement of `000 915 105 DE`?
- With `000 915 105 DE`, should I try to find a batch by Interstate, Enertec, or another vendor altogether? :-)
- I've heard some of them not advising to change the battery yourself, because then the onboard computer will not charge the new battery correctly.  Is there any truth to that?  What's involved in changing the battery spec for the onboard computer?

Comment: A car battery is just a battery. If the new one is 12v, and meets your cars crank amp requirement, and physically fits in the tray, it's fine. Just go to a place that sells car batteries and tell them you want one for whatever model car, and they'll give you one that fits. Differences are in various specs, see mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/33079/9884. If vw changed the part number on the batteries they sell then they changed the part number, who cares, they're not lying to you. 100% guarantee that ecu thing is irrelevant for your 2008 Jetta.

Comment: As this does not answer your question I am leaving it as a comment. Battery  and charging technology has advanced  in the last few years. Many newer batteries have AGM (advanced glassmat technology) The charge rate is different than that of a lead acid battery. To get the most out of this technology the computer must be told that the battery has been replaced.

Comment: @mikes AGM is lead acid (you probably mean AGM vs. wet cell), and you'll know if you buy one, it's not "Something To Watch Out For (TM)". Also not all cars that ship with AGM batteries have related ECU logic, just consult the owner's manual. I'd be surprised if those few didn't just auto recalibrate anyways after a power cut. I fear folks are getting easily confused by all these "just a note"s... changing a battery on an 08 Jetta is like changing a battery on flashlight.

Answer (score 7):

When I worked for BMW NA, I was the 'Merican engineer responsible for batteries, start, and charging systems on BMW vehicles stateside from about 1990-95.

There was some bean-counter thing that also changed *The Ultimate Driving Machine* [cough] from **Varta** to **Deta-Douglas** on some vehicles.  The issue was local sourcing of batteries... and money and profit...  As well as the stevadore's ability to drive new vehicles off the boat at Port Jersey after a transatlantic journey.

Enough glorydays.  To answer your question:

1. I have no idea, but I suspect color, branding, logos, and aesthetics.
2. Heck no.  A battery that fits and has at least as much CCA and Ah capacity as the OEM spec is fine.  Interstate is a phenomenal brand (Johnson Controls that also owns Varta, BTW), but there are others.  Varta is no slouch. Exide represents.  Do yourself a favor and don't pay for stickers and logos.  There are really very few battery manufacturers worldwide.
3. Moosepucky!  I cannot believe that a '08 Jetta can smell the brand of battery.  Now, having worked for several Germanal companies over the years, I could be wrong.  Now.  But not in 2008.  The alternator charges the battery until a *voltage* is achieved.  The capacity of the battery determines how many alternator joules it takes to achieve that charge.  That's it.

If the battery fits and has equal or better than OEM specs, you are golden.

Answer (score 5):

I think the focus of this question is an understanding of Volkswagen part numbers.

The Volkswagen part numbering scheme is fairly straight forward to understand once you know more about it.  Essentially all part numbers are in a fixed format and once you know the system, you will be able to work out which parts are interchangeable.  The format is as follows;

**NNN NNN NNN LLL**

(N = number, L = letter)

The first the blocks of three numbers are always present, the last three letters are optional.

The number of the first block signifies the vehicle type with the second two numbers, combined with the first identify the specific model.

For example, 111 is a Type 1 (passenger car) model 11 (Standard Beetle).  190 signifies an early Mk2 Golf (or Jetta), 1J0 actually refers to a Mk4 Golf platform vehicle (i.e. Golf, Jetta, Bora, etc...).  1K0 is Mk5 and 1K5 is Mk6 (as the Mk6 acutally used a revised Mk5 platform, hence the major model letter being the same).

The first number of the second group of numbers relates to the main part category and the second two, the sub-category.  The main parts categories are as follows;

1,Engine
2, Fuel Exhaust and Heating System
3, Transmission
4, Front End
5, Rear Axle
6, Wheels and Brakes
7, Bumpers Levers Pedals
8, Body
9, Electrical

The final group of three numbers is the component code.  The final digit of this number group is, for parts which fit a specific side of the car, always an even number when it's fitted to the right side of the vehicle and an odd number for the left hand side.

The optional letters following the part (upto a maximum of three) signify variations and updates.  These always run alphabetically.  These are for when there is a revision to a part or a part is superseded.  A part with the same numbers but different letters will typically be interchangeable.

Lets take a look at the specifics of what you've asked;

> 1J0 915 105 AD

1J0 = Mk4 Golf platform.  This does not mean that this is the ONLY vehicle this parts fits, just that this was the FIRST vehicle in which this part was used

915 = 9 = Electrical group.  I don't have a specific list of sub-groups but I would assume 15 relates to the battery and charging system.

105 = The specific battery specification (the fact 5 is odd irrelevant as there is only one battery on the car, however the battery in a Mk4 Golf is fitted on the left hand side of the car, when viewed from sitting in the drivers seat).

AD = revision code, the original part number will have been something like 1J0 915 105 which will have been replaced with 105 A then eventually 105 AD

> 000 915 105 DE

000 = No vehicle code, generic part (i.e. fits any vehicle)

915 = electric group, presumably battery and charging system sub-group

105 = the specific battery specification

DE = revision code, DE alphabetically supersedes AD

In answer to your second question, I'd personally go with whatever brand I'm comfortable fitting based on the best price with a reasonable warranty period.

Your final question, I am aware that some of the Mk6 platform (1K5) cars do need their batteries coded in, this is usually restricted to the Bluemotion models as these have a sophisticated charging system which supports regenerative braking via an "intelligent" alternator.  I would doubt that your car would need to be coded in and I've seen many examples of Mk5 (and some Mk6) platform owners who've replaced their battery without issue.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Not a real answer, just some information regarding that part about why you should not change the battery:

On cars with start/stop system the battery gets highly stressed. So the ecu tries to simulate/calculate the current battery charge/capacity. Should the battery be "unfit" the ecu tries to preserve battery charge by disabling the start/stop system. For this reason the ecu needs to know the current battery characteristics and expects to get the data reprogrammed when a battery change happens.

Page 13
[Bosch](https://aa-boschap-de.resource.bosch.com/media/en/commonly_used_media/common_media/ap_common/parts/de_6/engine_systems__auto_parts_1/starters_alternators__engine_systems_1/start_stopp_kompetenz.pdf)

Comment: The '08 Jetta ([5th gen](http://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?5919177-Battery-Replacement-for-wife-s-09-Jetta-2-5)) doesn't need any special considerations here.